# Hiding label of radiobutton after clicking and never show it again (html/css only)

Tags: html, css, checkbox, focus

I want a label for a radio button (#green) to appear when I select a certain checkbox (#red). Ok, this was not much of a problem. But what I wanted furthermore is, that after clicking the label, #green should be checked and the label should disappear ... and shall never come back, not even when #green is not checked anymore.

I thought about the following condition: the label is only visible when #red is checked and has :focus. But unfortunately the :focus of #red is lost BEFORE the click is applied to #green, so #green is never checked.

Here's the code:

```css
input + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#red + label {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  left: 100px;
}

#green + label {
  display: none;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  left: 200px;
}

#blue + label {
  display: none;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  left: 300px;
}

#blue:checked + label {
  display: block;
}

#red:checked + label {
  display: none;
}

#red:checked:focus ~ #green + label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="red" type="checkbox">
<label for="red" tabindex="3"></label>

<input id="green" type="radio" name="radios">
<label for="green" tabindex="1"></label>

<input id="blue" type="radio" name="radios" checked>
<label for="blue" tabindex="2"></label>
```

So, after clicking the red square, a green square should appear. And after clicking the green square, the green square and the blue square should disappear.

I hope somebody can help!

Comment: You want to hide 'red/green' checker after clicking it?

Answer (score 0):

it was interesting, but probably js could make it lot faster.

[Codepen for you](http://codepen.io/icrosil/pen/jbvEpv).

Ive added there the main part:

`#red:checked ~ #green + a:target {
    display: none;
}`

it looks like you want, the main hack with `a` element and target.

Comment: hello! thank you for your reply, but thats not exactly what I want. I want to hide the green box, after clicking it. And Í want to hide it 'forever'. That means: even if corresponding radiobutton is not checked anymore, the green label should stay hidden.

Comment: hmm, yeah I thought about the target hack also, but problem is still, that when I click the anchor surrounding the green box, the #green radiobutton is not selected...

Comment: Per documentation you can not do what you want, as you want to use only CSS you have to use workaround with `target` and such a methods leads you to 2 nested clickable elements which will fire only one of them, to prevent this situations (or allow) `jquery` for example has special method. Also you can try [focus](http://vanseodesign.com/css/click-events/) way, but as previous one it is not a solution.